# How to export vertex colors

Tags: export, vertex-colors

this is a follow-up to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271985/how-to-bake-texture-to-vertex-colors) other question.
I now have a mesh with vertex colors applied as attribute inside the Object Data Properties.
I have tried to export this mesh into various formats, including .ply, .fbx and .gltf, which are supposedly saving vertex colors.
However if I reimport the file the vertex colors are all lost, as well the original color attribute.
So I tried to use the Geometry nodes, thinking that maybe the Vertex Color layer was not properly written into the geometry.
I added a socket of type Color to the Group Output tree and I linked the Color Attribute to it, and then I applied the transform.
The expectation is that the vertex color becomes a property of geometry itself rather than an external attribute, so removing the attribute would maintain the color of the mesh, however the information is lost.
So I'm wondering if the geometry nodes are required at all, and which one is the format that keeps vertex color (some say .obj exporter will not keep it and to use .ply, others say to use .fbx, others collada).
Thank you

Comment: What type of color attribute are you using (domain/datatype) and what version of Blender? Traditional vertex colors (Face Corner + Byte Color) will be best supported since the other kinds were only added in 3.2 and exporters haven't been updated. I believe exporting to glTF or OBJ (non-legacy) should work with all kinds if you're using 3.3/3.4 though.

Comment: That did it! I was using Vertex domain and Color data type, switching to Face Corner and Byte Color correctly exports the vertex colors! @scurest You may want to post an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of trying to solve this same issue, I think I have worked it out.
You need to convert the *Color* attribute to *Byte Color* under the *Attributes* .

[image]